# Hibernate WrongClassException / Sets / Discriminators?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, set, one-to-many

The problem looks like this:

1. A **Product** table. 3 `joined-subclasses`: **DVD**, **CD**, **Book**.
2. A **Role** table (composite id: NAME, ROLE, PRODUCT), and subclasses by discriminator column ROLE: actor, director, artist, author, etc.. which are mapped to Actor, Director, Artist, Author java classes; (pretty usual I guess) ...
3. A **Book** has authors, a **CD** artists, a **DVD** actors and directors - these are all modelled via `set` with a `one-to-many` relation pointing to the class of the items, e.g. Author, Director, Artist, etc.. which are just subclasses of Role (see 2.)

As long as a joined-subclass has only one such set (of people/roles), all works fine. But when it has two, like **DVD**, actors and directors, Hibernate throws a WrongClassException?

XML excerpt (Product.hbm.xml):

```
<joined-subclass name="media.DVD" table="V_DVD"  lazy="false">

    <key column="IDPRODUCT"/>
    <property column="FORMAT" name="format" type="string"/>

    ...
    <set name="actors" lazy="false">
       <key column="IDPRODUCT"/>
       <one-to-many class="media.DVD$Actor"/>
    </set>

    <set name="directors" lazy="false">
       <key column="IDPRODUCT"/>
       <one-to-many class="media.DVD$Director"/>
    </set>
    ...
</joined-subclass>
```

XML (Person.hbm.xml):

```
<class name="media.Person" table="V_ROLE">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property column="NAME" name="name" type="string"/>
        <key-property column="ROLE" name="role" type="string"/>
        <key-many-to-one class="media.Product" column="IDPRODUCT" 
          name="product"/>
    </composite-id>

    <discriminator column="ROLE" insert="false" type="string"/>

    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="role"/>

    <many-to-one class="media.Product" column="IDPRODUCT" 
      insert="false" name="product" update="false"/>

    <subclass discriminator-value="author" name="media.Book$Author"/>
    <subclass discriminator-value="artist" name="media.Music$Artist"/>
    <subclass discriminator-value="creator" name="media.DVD$Creator"/>
    <subclass discriminator-value="director" name="media.DVD$Director"/>
    <subclass discriminator-value="actor" name="media.DVD$Actor"/>

</class>
```

It seems somewhat ok to me, yet it throws an exception. 
Thank you for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

I've got to say, this is a rather esoteric mapping. Why are you using a composite key (with discriminator being a part of it no less) instead of surrogate?

One possible issue here is you may be manually setting discriminator value (via `role` property) to something other than what it should be for given subclass. Hibernate won't be able to overwrite it (discriminator is mapped with insert="false") and this would cause a WrongClassException on subsequent select.

It's also possible that there' something funky going on in the `Product` mapping from which media.DVD extends and which you didn't include. Can you add that as well as provide full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically that your model is not normalized: You tell hibernate that there is a composite key, but you use only part of that key to reference the table.

I think you can implement this by either having a set of people in your product and each person has a role, or by mapping each set to a separate (linking) table with your person table.

Another more esoteric approach would be to map to a [`MultiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html): In fact you have a `Map<Role, Set<Person>>` in your product. Hibernate does not support this out of the box, but [I once wrote a UserType for this](http://blog.xebia.com/2007/10/05/mapping-multimaps-with-hibernate/).

Cheers,

-Maarten

Comment: Not sure where you got this from. OP's is using composite key for child (Person), parent (media.DVD) has a single (IDPRODUCT) key.